# How to get the difference between data between columns?

Tags: r

![result table][1]

I am looking to get produce a new dataframe (or simply add another column) that gives the difference between `start` and `stop`

How might I go about doing this?

I tried this:

```
difference <- c(df$start, df$stop)
```

However, even though it produced an output, it was not correct.

This error pops up as well:

> In Ops.factor(df$start, df$stop) :
>     ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: You can do `df_eat_length$TIME_STOP - df_eat_length$TIME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference would be `-`.  In the OP's code, it is doing concatenation (`c`)

```
difference <- as.numeric(as.character(df$stop)) - 
               as.numeric(as.character(df$start))
```